# python - changing the color of a word in a png file (search for the word and change the color of the word)

Tags: python

I am generating PNG images using wordcloud. My file consists of over 220000 entries with frequencies, to generate wordcloud (hence its slow).
I have to generate wordclouds in a loop and look for a string in file and change the color of that word to red (rest of the words will be in black).

Can anyone guide me to a way to search a specific word in the PNG image and just change the color of that word in the PNG file using python???[For instance, in the attached image would like to search for a word like game,and change its color to red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InCOE.png)

I have already tried to generate wordcloud using wordcloud function in python and used the following function to change color. Using this function I can change the color but as I have to generate hundreds of images, it takes alot of time. 
I was looking for a way to generate the image once and then search for specific words in the image and just change the color of that word using python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
#to get rid of warning of open windows
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.max_open_warning': 0})
import os.path

stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
d={}

##################################################################
def color_word(word, *args, **kwargs):
        if (word == name.upper()):
            color = '#ff0000' # red
        else:
            color = '#000000' # black
        return color
##################################################################
with open('f1.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line.split(',')
        d[parts[0]]=float(parts[1])

with open('f2.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
       parts = line.split()
       name=parts[0]
       print(name)
       wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                                  background_color='white',
                                  max_words=210000,
                                  width=1500,
                                  height=1000, color_func=color_word).generate_from_frequencies(d)                   
       plt.figure(figsize = (15, 15), facecolor = None)
       plt.imshow(wordcloud)
       plt.axis("off")
       plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)
       # plt.savefig(name+".eps",format='eps', dpi=1000)
       wordcloud.to_file(name+".png")

Here are few entries from both the files.
f1.txt-
RON,3345.4859813084113
ABODE,63170.64705882353
ARM,12634.129411764707
DELL,27535.923076923078
GAME,56521.10526315789
ANI,357967.0
HEAD,357967.0
CARD,46691.34782608696
LAMP,357967.0
STAR,357967.0
WAR,357967.0
EPISODE,357967.0

f2.txt-
RON,ABODE,ARM,DELL,GAME,ANI,HEAD,CARD,LAMP,STAR,WAR,EPISODE,HOPE,NEW
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: What do you mean  _"I am generating PNG images using wordcloud"_?  are you using an external program, a web application or a Python program that you have written?  My question is relevant because PNG is a bitmap format and you cannot easily find a specific word in it... I may be wrong but you have to change the color **before** committing the PNG file.  Another possibility is to save the image using a different format (PDF?) and then use a Python tool (that exists...) to modify the file.  If you want to give this additional info, please don't reply in a comment but rather [edit] your question.

Comment: I understand what you mean, maybe I was not clear in my explanation. As u mentioned, I tried to save the wordcloud result as pdf. Can you guide me to some python tools that I can use an change the color of specific words in a pdf file. Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Moving on to the rest of your comment, I'm not an expert in PDF manipulation, I just know that there is plenty of info on the web and on SO about "python pdf". Have a look at the results of a search, put your hands to some coding and when you have problems come back with new questions.

Comment: You are likely overcomplicating the issue: if you describe the way you generate the original wordcloud, it would be much simpler to intervene before the PNG file is created, than after it is created and converted to PDF. Do you use [this](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/) library?

Comment: Dear @DanielR. I can change the color using the above function before the PNG file is created. I want to find a way using python so that, In a image (PNG/PDF/JPEG), I want to search for a single word at a time within a loop and change the color of only that word in the image (basically I need different images with some specific words highlighted or colored in each image using the first Image). So instead of creating multiple images, I want to edit one image everytime. Sorry if my explanation is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear unfortunately. You say `I can change the color using the above function before the PNG file is created`: can you please post the code that creates the PNG file, and preferably all other pieces of your code? From your comment I understand that you have a procedure for creating the wordcloud, and outputting it to a PNG file: please post all of it in the question above. Also, the name of the function `random_color_func` is misleading, if you are working with other people they will not know that there is no randomness: it's fully deterministic in fact.

Comment: @DanielR. as u mentioned, I have added my code above. Hope it's gonna make more sense now.

Comment: Ok, better. Yes it is possible to interfere with the color map of wordcloud. I tried to parse a couple of books from project guthenberg with your code, but it doesn't work. Can you post a few lines for each of the two files, `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`, that are parsed with your code in the manner that you expect? It's very important to make your work reproducible by the other users of SO, it helps a lot the chances of getting an answer. Also your parser is not correct, you forgot to `file.read()` or `file.readlines()` your files.

Comment: @DanielR. Thanks for letting me know about the parser. I have edited my post and added some content of files.

Comment: Ehm I posted a solution for parsing a standard document. It looks like you are working with .csv files, at least the first one is. That code below works if you change the split on the `','` instead of the `' '`, but you will have to take only the first element in each line. Also, since you are using csv files, there are better ways to perform vectorized operations on their columns/rows: calling .lower() on the full column of a pandas dataframe containing the words should take less time than iterating over each word. Either ways, the code below should still work with minor adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Ok nevermind I modified the parser too.
This works, you will have to re-adapt the parser to the specific nature of your texts.

Please read the comments: I have added suggestion on good programming practices that you may want to follow when writing code that is read by other people.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import numpy as np # Not used, do not import
# from PIL import Image # Not used, do not import
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
#to get rid of warning of open windows     # No, bad habit. Do not remove warnings until the moment you are ready
# plt.rcParams.update({'figure.max_open_warning': 0})    # to ship the final version of your code.
# import os.path # Not used, do not import

stopwords = set(STOPWORDS) # I think it also accepts stopwords as a list, check it
vocabulary = dict()
word_in_red = 'the'

def color_word(word, *args, **kwargs):
        if (word == word_in_red):
            color = '#ff0000' # red
        else:
            color = '#000000' # black
        return color

with open('f1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file: # Do not use inf, it may be mistaken for numpy.inf
    for line in file.readlines(): # reads all lines one by one
        for word in line.split(' '): # parses each line, returns the words splits by blank spaces
            word_lower = word.lower() # lowers the case
            if word_lower not in vocabulary: # if word not in vocabulary, puts word in vocabulary with counter 1
                vocabulary[word_lower] = 1
            else: # else increases the counter by 1
                vocabulary[word_lower] += 1 

with open('f2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file: # Same as above, don't use inf
    for line in file.readlines():
        for word in line.split(' '):
            word_lower = word.lower()
            if word_lower not in vocabulary:
                vocabulary[word_lower] = 1
            else:
                vocabulary[word_lower] += 1 

    wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                              background_color='white',
                              max_words=210000,
                              width=1500,
                              height=1000, color_func=color_word).generate_from_frequencies(vocabulary)                   

    plt.figure(figsize = (15, 15), facecolor = None)
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)
    plt.show()
    # plt.savefig(name+".eps",format='eps', dpi=1000) # Why is this here? I understand you want to save with
    # wordcloud
    wordcloud.to_file('wordcloud.png')
    print('Done')
```

Output:

[image: WordCloud, 'the' in red]

Comment: Dear @Daniel R, thanks alot for your reply and code. I was able to generate the image and I have added it in my post above (yes, I had done some modifications in my code). If u can notice in my program, I generate wordcloud for each word in f2.txt (my original file contains 220000 entries). I dont want to generate 220000 png images using wordcloud function, I would like to generate one image (with all words in black , let call it fig1.png) and for each word in f2.txt, I would like to read fig1.png, search for the particular word and then change the color of that word.

Comment: It is not clear what you want, you may not be using the correct terminology. Do you want to perform convolution on a set of images, in order to identify a certain word/feature in them from a set of possible words/labels, and classify that image accordingly? And then change the color of the image in the position that corresponds to the identified word? If this is the case, it will take you maybe one month of work to develop a ConvNet that can browse successfully through a wordcloud, and you will likely fail. You may want to redefine your task's objectives if this is the case.

Comment: Sorry again for the poor explanation, ur previous comment defines my problem, its too bad if i can't perform convolution on set of images and change certain content in the images. Thanks alot for your help @Daniel R.

Comment: @su213 You're welcome. If you like the answer received you can still select it :)

Comment: is there a way to do the convolution (the explanation provided) on .eps or pdf files??? I looked and didn't find a way that could work, could you guide on this??? Thanks in advance for ur reply :)

Comment: You can do [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) on pdfs, yes, but this is largely outside the scope of the question. You will not be able to easily implement any pre-made algorithm to your task, though. An expert in machine learning that will develop a working solution for doing [pattern recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition) on such noisy images as wordclouds will require about a month of time, and anywhere between 5 and 20K euros in payment, and the accuracy will still be unsatisfactory. You should change the workflow, or your objective.